# Left margin is unexpectedly reduced

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, algorithms, algorithm2e

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[ noend, boxruled]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{algorithm}[H]
            \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
            \SetKwProg{fxn}{Function}{}{end} %To define functions like \fxn{name}{body}
            \Input{$a,b\in\mathbb N$}
            \Output{$\mathrm{gcd}(a,b)$}
            \textbf{Initialize} $X,Y\leftarrow 1$\;
            \While{$Y\le a$}{\If{$Y|a$\quad\&\quad$Y|b$}{$X\leftarrow Y$\;}$Y=Y+1$}
            \textbf{Output} $Y$
            \caption{$\mathrm{gcd}(a,b)$}
        \end{algorithm}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Above is an MWE for my problem. Why is the `center` environment not working here? And why is the  left margin so bad? How to make it normal like in article class? Taking it within `minipage` with `\centering` is also not helping here.

**Edit** The output of above MWE is [image] and the desired output is (except the width of the box, that is immaterial here).[image]

See the difference in the left margin of the box.

Comment: Why don't you use the `frame` environment?

Comment: @Bernard, Do you mean adding `\usepackage{framed}` in the beginning and then enclosing the algorithm in `oframed` environment? That doesn't help. I want the heading of the algorithm to be on the top instead of the bottom that this does.

Comment: No I only meant the frame environment(, defined by beamer.

Comment: @Bernard Oh so you mean that which defines a new slide? I am asking about horizontal alignment actually, that is unaltered by presence/absence of frame in this case.

Comment: What kind of output do you expect and how does your current output look like?

Comment: @leandriis, Edited and included that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- the `center` environment is working, but the width of the algorithm is equal to the width of the text, so you don't see any difference. If you decrease the width of the algorithm, you will see the effect
- you can adjust the margin by setting `\algomargin`

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[ noend, boxruled]{algorithm2e}

\setlength{\algomargin}{1em}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}
       \begin{algorithm}[H]
           \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
           \SetKwProg{fxn}{Function}{}{end} %To define functions like \fxn{name}{body}
           \Input{$a,b\in\mathbb N$}
           \Output{$\mathrm{gcd}(a,b)$}
           \textbf{Initialize} $X,Y\leftarrow 1$\;
           \While{$Y\le a$}{\If{$Y|a$\quad\&\quad$Y|b$}{$X\leftarrow Y$\;}$Y=Y+1$}
           \textbf{Output} $Y$
           \caption{$\mathrm{gcd}(a,b)$}
       \end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]